# Can't setup amazon elastic beanstalk cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to setup a deployment to EB from a command line. I've installed eb utility. I've done eb init, provided AWS credentials, was said everything was ok. Then when I type eb status I am said ERROR: Your credentials are not valid. However I do know they are valid. I launched 2 instances and tried this. On ubuntu everything was ok, but on Amazon Linux I get the error I've written above. How can I fix that? Thanks.

Comment: What version of python are you using on the Amazon Linux?

Comment: eb --version returns
EB CLI 3.0.6 (Python 2.7.5)

Comment: Do you have aws credentials set up in your environment variables?

Comment: Yes, but no luck... I used this: https://gist.github.com/jnrbsn/8062545 and now I can run eb as root, but cannot as ec2-user - I am said the credentials is invalid.

Comment: Have you tried this recently with a newer version of the CLI?

Comment: No, as I've said above I can run eb as root. That works for me. So,  I stopped working on that.

Answer (score 1):

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=597475&#597475 Here is the explanation and the solution.